# Spring 3.1 cache - how to use the returned value in the SpEL

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-el

I am trying to make an eviction of an entry in a Spring-managed cache (Spring 3.1 abstraction).

I need to refer to the returned value of the method in the SpEL of the "key" property in the annotation:

```
    /* (How to refer to the 'T' returned value in the "KEY_ID"?) */
@Caching(evict = { @CacheEvict(value = CACHE_BY_ID, key = KEY_ID) })
public T delete(AppID appID, UserID userID) throws UserNotFoundException {
    return inner.delete(appID, userID);
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Spring-Security-3 (at 1:04:00), Wiesner uses filterObject as a handle to the return value, but that's probably only a Spring Security handle. Worth a shot I guess.

Comment: You can't, yet, see [SPR-8871](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8871) and get involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there is any way to reference the returned object:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-spel-context

But why do you need to do that? You can refer to the arguments in the @CacheEvict "key" value, e.g.:

```
@CacheEvict(value = CACHE_BY_ID, key = "#userID")
public T delete(AppID appID, UserID userID) throws UserNotFoundException {
...
}
```

More example code in response to response below about having to evict from multiple caches using multiple properties of a User object:

```
@Caching(evict = {
    @CacheEvict(value = CACHE_BY_ID, key = "#user.userID"),
    @CacheEvict(value = CACHE_BY_LOGIN_NAME, key = "#user.loginName")
    // etc.
})
public T delete(AppID appID, User user) throws UserNotFoundException {
...
}
```

Comment: The T-class object returned by "delete" is an object like this: 
class User {
  UserID userID;
  LoginName loginName;
  EmailAddress emailAddress;
  ...
}.
I have more than one cache - one by userID, other by loginName, other by emailAddress. When I remove an entry by userID, I'd like to expire also entries in the other two caches... and these keys are contained in the return value, so it'd be great if I could do: @CacheEvict(key="#returnValue.loginName"...), @CacheEvict(key="#returnValue.emailAddress"...)

Comment: You could do that if you passed in the User object as the argument, instead of the UserID, as you could then reference the different user properties in SpEL. You'd have to combine that with the \@Caching annotation if you need to do multiple differently configured \@CacheEvict's: 

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-caching

Comment: I edited my answer with some more example code that may better fit your situation, based on your comment.

Comment: passing the whole User is not a good solution for this kind of case - but the only one I can think of from older versions. I seem to recall however that it's going to be supported in newer versions, I saw a related JIRA in Spring...

Answer (score 3):

try using #result in your SpEL

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above and according to `Table 29.1 of the Cache SpEL available metadata at`  at
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

it is possible to use #result in 'unless' expressions and 'cache evict' expressions only when beforeInvocation is false.

To confirm, I have recently used #result successfully in @CacheEvict.